# What image sizes should i add in the ios7 project?

Tags: image, ios7

I am a little bit confused with iOS7 , should i add the 2x only images? or also add the small size?
and i read in app store documentation , that my app must support ipad? But i want it to be on iphone only , and if so why whatsapp is only on iphone.

Please help ,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app supports **only iPhone** devices with **iOS 7 and later** then you need add **only @2x** images because the minimum iPhone model that supports iOS 7 is iPhone 4 that has retina display and require images with double definition.
If your app supports iPad then you need also add images with small sizes because the the minimum iPad model that supports iOS 7 is iPad 2 that has non-retina display.

According to your second question: You could support only iPhone if needed, it isn't obligatory to support both devices types (iPhone and iPad).